# How to disable or hide Tags using Vueform/multiselect librabry?

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I've got the following code and it's working fine. When I click in the search bar a dropdown shows up and when I select an option, the tag is displayed in the search bar. I'd like to hide or disable it but I can't find anything to solve that in the documentation.

Link to the image of how the dropdown currently looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9CLv.jpg

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Multiselect
      v-model="value"
      mode="tags"
      :hideSelected="false"
      :caret="false"
      :close-on-select="false"
      :searchable="true"
      :create-option="true"
      :options="options"
    />
    
    {{ value }}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Multiselect from "@vueform/multiselect";
export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: [],
      options: [
        { value: "batman", label: "Batman" },
        { value: "robin", label: "Robin" },
        { value: "joker", label: "Joker" },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style src="@vueform/multiselect/themes/default.css"></style>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9CLv.jpg
```

Comment: The selected ones will be available and visible from the dropdown. As you can see in my code I have hideSelected="false". I find it not neat, to have the selected options visible in the dropdown which doesn't get hidden when a user makes a selection and at the same time having the selected options displayed in the search bar. So a user, sees what they've selected twice. Your thoughts are welcomed on that.

Comment: The background color of the selected ones will change to distinguish between the selected and not selected options.

Comment: I've edited the question and added a link to the image of the dropdown, kindly check that out https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9CLv.jpg. As you can see from the image when the first and the third options are selected, not only do their background colors change but they still remain visible in the dropdown. When hideSelected is set to true, then the selected ones get removed from the dropdown as soon as they are selected. What I'm trying to achieve is, to only have the placeholder in the search bar "Search name" and not the selected options as the user can already see what they select highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to set the `mode` to `multiple` instead of `tags`.

When options are selected in `multiple` mode, the search bar indicates the number of options selected instead of their values:

```html
<Multiselect mode="multiple" />
```

[image: screenshot 1]

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vueform-multiselect-multiple-mode)

If you prefer that label be the placeholder, a workaround is to specify `multipleLabel` as a function that returns the placeholder string:

```html
<template>
  <Multiselect mode="multiple"
               placeholder="Characters"
               :multipleLabel="() => 'Characters'"
               />
</template>

<style scoped>
/* keep the multiple-label text light */
:deep(.multiselect-multiple-label) {
  color: #ababab;
}
</style>
```

[image: screenshot 2]

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vueform-multiselect-multiple-mode-placeholder-only?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Comment: Perfect, demo two is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank you!